# Adding a character string to every line in a file, incrementing that character string added by 1 each file

Tags: macos, unix, qiime

I have some set of files with character strings in lines such that there is a folder containing

```
file1
file2
file3
```

and within those files there a variable length lists of strings of characters such that file 1 may read

```
file1.itemA
file1.itemB
file1.itemC
```

While file 2 may only contain

```
file2.itemA
file2.itemB
```

I want to add a file specific code to every line within each file such that

```
code1.file1.itemA
code1.file1.itemB
code1.file1.itemC
```

And

```
code2.file2.itemA
code2.file2.itemB
```

How can I do this within unix? I am using the OSX terminal to execute commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not near a terminal to test, but, how about:

```
cd /path/to/your/files
word='code'
base=1
for file in *; do sed -i -e "s/^/$word$base/" "${file}"; base=$(( $base + 1 )); done
```

The `$word` variable is the constant you want.  The `$base` variable holds the count that is incremented on each file, initially set to 1.

Comment: Gotcha. can you clarify- what if the file names are not simple file1, file2, etc. but rather

    'file01_rep01_other.meaningless.stuff.fastq'
    'file02_rep02_other.meaningless.stuff.fastq'

Comment: Should be fine. The file name is not used in the calculation of the code to add, and the file name argument to `sed` is quoted properly.  If you get a specific error, post the specific error and as much of the actual files as you are allowed.